# RFC 6979 - Why not simply hash the message & the private key for deterministic ECDSA?

Tags: dsa

Why go through the trouble of using the HMAC_DRBG process, instead of simply hashing `[message | private key]` to calculate $k$ for [deterministic ECDSA](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6979)?

If the resulting $k$ or the signature is invalid, then a known byte value can be appended to the input, and re-hashed, until an acceptable result is achieved:
`k=h([message|privateKey|0x00 … 0x00])`

As many `0x00` bytes as the number of iterations it takes.

Am I missing an inherent weakness here?

Edit: If the hash function output length is smaller than the curve order, multiple hash outputs (produced by appending a known byte, similar to what was described above) can be concatenated as necessary:
`k=[ h([message|privateKey]) | h([message|privateKey|0x00]) ... ]`
Once you have enough output, you can then truncate it to match the curve order bit length.

And if the resulting $k$ or the signature is no good, then restart with the known byte appended:
`k=[ h([message|privateKey|0x00]) | h([message|privateKey|0x00 0x00]) ... ]`

And so on, until an acceptable $k$ is produced.

Comment: It decouples the output length of the hash function from the required length of k. I would have said it was to provide security even in the presence of a collision in the hash function, but I don't think it does.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I added the necessary info to the question. As for the collisions, I don't see them being an issue.

Comment: How would you handle the case when the order of generator is of larger bit size than your hash function digest  (e.g. SHA-256 and P-521) ?

Comment: That was Michael's point as well I believe. I initially had thought you would just restrict the usage to curves smaller than the hash size, but it would also be feasible to just do the iteration I described and keep appending until enough output is available to match the curve order bit length.

Comment: Or you could use a sponge based hash like SHA3 that can have an arbitrary output length.

Comment: Definitely. Though that may be bit too limiting

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Deterministic signatures are safe in the random oracle model. Using HMAC_DRBG allowed me to rely on existing research on the safety of that construction and how close it comes to a "true" random oracle. If I had used any other "handmade" construction, then I would have had to provide extensive analysis on why it is secure. Being naturally lazy, I chose HMAC_DRBG.

Moreover, this use of HMAC_DRBG makes the end result more "convincing" -- and a large part of specifying a cryptographic algorithm *as a RFC* is to get other people to use it.

(If I had been aware of its existence at that time, I might have considered [HKDF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5869) instead of HMAC_DRBG, but that does not matter much in practice.)

Comment: Is prof Bernstein providing any "extensive analysis" on why it is secure his deterministic nonce derivation in EdDSA ?

Comment: In [their article](http://ed25519.cr.yp.to/ed25519-20110926.pdf), the EdDSA authors mostly say that: "Standard PRF hypotheses imply that this pseudorandom session key _r_ is indistinguishable from a truly random string generated independently for each
_M_, so there is no loss of security". This is a bit too terse to be called "extensive analysis" but it makes sense. For more analysis, you may read the Leurent & Nguyen article cited from RFC 6979 (under the reference "LN2009"); that article includes some analysis and pointers.