# Why does RFC 6979 need so many loops?

Tags: dsa, rfc6979

I recently started reading [RFC 6979](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/pdfrfc/rfc6979.txt.pdf). I'm curious why it needs so many loops.

This post asks a similar question: ["RFC 6979 - Why not simply hash the message & the private key for deterministic ECDSA?"](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20538/rfc-6979-why-not-simply-hash-the-message-the-private-key-for-deterministic-e), but my doubts are still unanswered.

Why can't the $k$ used in ECDSA be just like $k  =  SHA256(sk + HASH(m))$ ?

Is it just because HMAC_DRBG has a better security proof ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The existing security proofs for DSA and ECDSA require k to be chosen uniformly at random. HMAC_DRBGB is already an approved CSPRNG for use in either signature scheme. So this just changes the instantiation and entropy source, making it a minimal change for existing implementations to add. See section 3.5, "Rationale"